# Сетевое приложение на WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms

Собираюсь написать сетевое приложение на WinForms для обработки заказов внутри предприятия, приложение будет лежать на сетевом диске, откуда пользователи будут его запускать. 
Приложение будет использовать базу данных SQL Express, который работает у меня на ПК. 
Около 10 пользователей будут принимать заказы и заносить информацию в приложении, информация будет записываться в базу данных(на моем ПК)
Далее заказ запускается в цех (для этого формируется бумажная версия заказа), проходит этапы обработки (всего около 5 этапов).
На каждом этапе, рабочий штрихует, то что такой то этап выпонил(штрихует номер заказа и свой бейджик) и эти данные записываются в базу данных.

Главный вопрос: Можно ли так делать вообще? т.е. не создавать клиентское приложение и серверное приложение отдельно, а делать как единый проект с прямым подключение к бд.

Comment: Запуск удаленных приложений на терминальном сервере возможен. Но в большинстве вам тут понадобятся навыки администрирования, чем программирования. Ну и в принципе сам сервер, который это потянет.

Comment: Как я понимаю, при запуске приложения с стевого диска приложение ресурсы сервера будет жрать или локального пользователя? Если будет нагрузка на сервер, то можно программу копировать например на рабочий стол и запускать оттуда.

Comment: Нет, так не пойдет. Просто положить программу в сетевую папку, не достаточно для того, чтобы ее начал исполнять сервер. Кто запустил - тот и исполняет,  только директория с файлами приложения будет сетевой, а не локальной. Чтобы исполнялось на сервере, со всеми преимуществами и недостатками такого подхода, нужен терминальный сервер. С прямым подключением к БД делать можно, если вас не волнует вопрос безопасности, например, внутри защищенного сегмента сети.

Comment: А я в школе проходил Аксесс)